# File Upload and Compare using IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using File Upload. Then compare this file with a repository using IEnumerable. I want the IEnumerable list to save the path of the uploaded file. I am trying to do so, but it's giving me an error :
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Uploaded file.txt'

The code is as follows:

//File upload method uploads the file

```
protected string File_Upload()
{
        string strFilename;
        strFilename = File1.PostedFile.FileName;
        strFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilename);
        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"E:\" + strFilename); /*saves the uploaded file in the specified directory */
        return strFilename; /*returns the file name and it's path*/

}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String StrFileNmae =File_Upload(); /* Receives the file name and path*/
        string file1 = StrFileNmae;

        IEnumerable<string> list1 = File.ReadLines(file1);
        IEnumerable<string> list2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"E:\DocxDB", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        IList<string> difference = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
        if (difference != null)
        {
            lbl_Result.Text = "Files do not match.";
        }

}
```

Comment: If you bring up Windows Explorer and paste ''C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Uploaded file.txt' into the address bar, does the file load in Notepad?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush No is does not loads.

Comment: I assume that File1.PostedFile.FileName is 'c:\ ... Uploaded file.txt' - you've not shown where this is set. Your program can't open a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Initially on uploading the file I stored it in,'E:\...'. using this. And Gave it's bath too. But IEnumerable is not taking file from 'E:\...' drive , but from 'c:\...'
     File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"E:\" + strFilename);

Comment: Edit your post, add the code.

Comment: I had already added all the code. Added comments for your convenience. :)

Comment: Where is the code that sets 'File1.PostedFile.FileName'? File_Upload() checks this but I can't see where it is being set. It's likely the error is caused at that point

Comment: I don't know how and where to set that. According to me 
         strFilename = File1.PostedFile.FileName;                  sets the strfilename to the name of the file being uploaded using .FileName of the .PostedFile. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the File_Upload method returns the file name but not the path it's in. Without a path the server will try and load it from the current directory.

```
protected string File_Upload()
{
        string strFilename;
        strFilename = File1.PostedFile.FileName;
        strFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilename);
        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"E:\" + strFilename); /*saves the uploaded file in the specified directory */
        return @"E:\" + strFilename; // <--- Change is here

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Sorry I took to long to figure it out, I didn't notice the ASP.Net tag.

Comment: They say all is well that ends well. :)